# XML to postscript using xsltproc

Tags: c, xml, linux, xslt, postscript

I'm trying to produce a **postscript** file for an **XML** document. I can produce a plain text or an html output using ***xsltproc***.

```
xsltproc --output output.txt xslFile.xsl input.xml
```

Is there a way to produce a *postscript* file from command line or programmatically using C?

Comment: Isn't Postscript a text format? So you should be able to create it using `<xsl:output method="text"/>` and `--output result.ps`, as long as the author of the XSLT knows how to create syntactically correct Postscript code.

Comment: Is forming a postscript code using xsl the best way of doing this? I feel this makes it complex because the postscript code cannot be very dynamic but the XML will contain varying data fields which makes it complex to write a postscript code to contain all the xml fields? any opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility to achieve this is converting the XML-file to `XSL-FO` and then use [Apache-FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to transform it to a Postscript-file with

```
fop -xml input.xml -xsl xml2fo.xsl -ps output.ps
```

At the moment I couldn't find a simple XSL-file on the net for this task, but this depends on what you like the output to look anyway. Creating a basic XSLT for this transformation should not be that hard.

EDIT: Just for completeness: possible output-formats of `Apache-FOP` are

```
-pdf outfile      input will be rendered as PDF (outfile req'd)
-pdfa1b outfile   input will be rendered as PDF/A-1b compliant PDF
                    (outfile req'd, same as "-pdf outfile -pdfprofile PDF/A-1b")
-awt              input will be displayed on screen 
-rtf outfile      input will be rendered as RTF (outfile req'd)
-pcl outfile      input will be rendered as PCL (outfile req'd) 
-ps outfile       input will be rendered as PostScript (outfile req'd) 
-afp outfile      input will be rendered as AFP (outfile req'd)
-tiff outfile     input will be rendered as TIFF (outfile req'd)
-png outfile      input will be rendered as PNG (outfile req'd)
-txt outfile      input will be rendered as plain text (outfile req'd)
```

Comment: brill! that works great! thanks :-)
I like to add one thing to this, one could use the **Barcode4j** [extension](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/fop-ext.html) to _fop_ to output barcodes quite easily.